# How to read nested properties from configuration file in java

Tags: java

I want to read Name property from configuration file. I want my config file to look like this:

config.properties

```
Person{
  Name= ABC
  PhoneNumber=123
      }
Address{     
  Pin=500
       }
```

I tried

```
public Properties readConfiguration()
{
    File configFile1 = new File("config.properties");

    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(configFile1);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(reader);

        reader.close();
        return props;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        // file does not exist
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // I/O error
    }

    return null;
}
```

But this function will read only key value pairs and its unable to read nested properties. So what should i use to read nested properties?

Please help me find the solution to read nested properties.

Comment: I would suggest you for your given structure to use `YAML` file instead of `property` file.

Comment: How did you come to think that the above is an acceptable .properties file format? It's not. Here is a description of the file format: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader- If you want hierarchical properties like the above, you need to write your own parser.

Comment: Use Groovy and create a DSL for that. This structure is perfect for Groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not legal properties file.
But it is legal [HOCON](https://github.com/lightbend/config) conf.

An example of your conf file reading with hocon generated by [tscfg](https://github.com/carueda/tscfg).

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
import org.junit.Assert;

import java.io.File;

public class SampleConf {
    public final SampleConf.Address Address;
    public final SampleConf.Person Person;

    public static class Address {
        public final int Pin;

        public Address(final com.typesafe.config.Config c) {
            this.Pin = c.hasPathOrNull("Pin") ? c.getInt("Pin") : 500;
        }
    }

    public static class Person {
        public final java.lang.String Name;
        public final int PhoneNumber;

        public Person(final com.typesafe.config.Config c) {
            this.Name = c.hasPathOrNull("Name") ? c.getString("Name") : "ABC";
            this.PhoneNumber = c.hasPathOrNull("PhoneNumber") ? c.getInt("PhoneNumber") : 123;
        }
    }

    public SampleConf(final com.typesafe.config.Config c) {
        this.Address = new SampleConf.Address(c.getConfig("Address"));
        this.Person = new SampleConf.Person(c.getConfig("Person"));
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Config config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(
                new File(("problem.so.hocon.conf"))) // file path
                .resolve();
        final SampleConf conf = new SampleConf(config);
        // do everything  you like
        final SampleConf.Address address = conf.Address;
        final SampleConf.Person person = conf.Person;
        Assert.assertEquals(500, address.Pin);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

your file `config.properties` structure looks like json format and to my understanding you want to parse a json file, correct me if i am wrong. To read or write from a json objects u can use [Gson](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/) like this

my json file

```
{
    Person:{
     "Name" = "ABC",
      "PhoneNumber" = 123
      },
    Address: {
      "Pin" = 500
     }
}
```

My POJO classes includes

```
    public class Person {
        private String Name;
        private  int PhoneNumber;

        public Person() {
        }

        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            Name = name;
        }

        public int getPhoneNumber() {
            return PhoneNumber;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {
            PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }
    }
    public class  Address{
            private String Pin;

            public Address() {
            }

            public String getPin() {
                return Pin;
            }

            public void setPin(String pin) {
                Pin = pin;
            }
        }
public class Config{
        private Person person;
        private Address address;

    public Config() {
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

read the file convert to string and then read json object using Gson.

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("config.properties"));
        String fileStr="";
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            fileStr+=scanner.nextLine();
        }
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Config config =gson.fromJson(fileStr,Config.class);
        config.getPerson.getPhoneNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to directly answer your question, you are not doing a proper config.properties file.

normally, a property file would look like this as per your example:

```
//File 
Name=ABC
Phonenumber=123456
pin=1234
```

In your code, you should be fine by just doing the following after `***props.load(reader)***`  (Note I am not copying all your code.)

```
System.out.println(props.getProperty("Name")); // ABC
System.out.println(props.getProperty("Phonenumber")); // 123456
System.out.println(props.getProperty("pin")); // 123
```

Here I am simply outputting the results but note you can do whatever you wish to do.